# To schedule crontab on linux env for selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cron

I am running my selenium test case using "mvn clean test" and its working fine.
When tried to run it from crontab , getting error chrome driver crashed.

Tried to write shell script and provide pom , code directory etc but its of no help

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to inject into your `cron` script 2nd line:

```
 source /home/<your username>/.bash_profile
```

This will insert into your `cron` script all the required environment context and paths.

Comment: I tried but still unable to launch browser whreas when running shell script direct its launching browser